# load remote content and append url with #pageTitle

Tags: jquery

How do you load a remote file and append the page's URL with the loaded contents title or other attribute and make them bookmarkable? I need to be able to enter the appended URL and have that content loaded. The BBQ plug in is too bulky.

Using the following it appends the URL with #undefined

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#content").load(href, function() {
            var request=$(this).attr('id');                           
            window.location.hash = request.hash;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try sammy.js
http://sammyjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use ajax upload http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: Not sure I follow. I want to load the content into the parent page and append the parent pages url with the id of the div from the loaded page.

Comment: Ah, i thought you wanted to upload a file, then append the uploaded file's url somewhere

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, I'm a bit confused with the wording